# could any one explain me the below code.

Tags: sql-server-2008

Could any one help me understand the below code. Please help me how it works as i am new lerning sql server.

```
WITH SearchTerms(Term)
     AS (SELECT ' I '
         UNION ALL
         SELECT ' II '
         UNION ALL
         SELECT ' III '
         UNION All
         SELECT ' MD '
          UNION All
         SELECT ' M.D '
          UNION All
         SELECT ' M.D. '
          UNION All
         SELECT ' D.O '
           UNION All
         SELECT ' D.O. '
           UNION All
         SELECT ' DO '
         ),
     ToBeSearched(string)
     AS (SELECT 'sjfhasjdg III do ')
SELECT string,
       Term,
       Charindex(Term, string) AS Location
FROM   ToBeSearched
       JOIN SearchTerms
         ON Charindex(Term, string) > 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query is using two `Common Table Expressions` to then form a `SELECT` statement using an `INNER JOIN`.

The first Common Table Expression (CTE) is using a `UNION` to create a set of results for the table.

The second CTE contains just one record, with one column, with the value `'sjfhasjdg III do '`

The `SELECT` statement at the end of the query is filtering out the results from the first CTE dependant on the record in the second CTE.

The result set will be:

```
string               Term   Location
sjfhasjdg III do     III    10
sjfhasjdg III do     DO     14
```

See more on CTE's:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx

Comment: Tanq :-) I have understood CTE.

Comment: Result set is collation dependant.

Comment: collation dependant means what ?